# Can variables be used in Freeform notification template settings?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I've set up a notification template to notify the site owner when a form submission is received. I'd like to have the email notification be from the person who filled out the form and the from email to be their email, not the site owner's. Can I use form field variables in the notification template options to do this? If so, how should they be entered there (e.g., in brackets, just the field name, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any of the fields which exist in the form with which that notification template is related, via standard EE syntax (e.g., `{name}`, `{email}`, etc).

Comment: I tried this and it causes no notification to be sent at all. To be clear, I'm talking about entering variables in the notification template settings page, not the page where the actual form is.

Comment: To clarify - you mean like so? http://cl.ly/image/0s1p0X0V1Q2J (This screenshot is taken from a live site, where these variables are working just like this.)